# How can I switch between elements using AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

I am relatively new to Ajax. I've created two `<li>` elements with `<a>` elements inside of them, both of them lead to other HTML files. What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I click on one of the links, the page automatically loads the HTML file related to it, however its not working for me. Whenever I click on one of the links, nothing happens. Thanks in advance! I am using JQuery with Ajax.

FIRST HTML FILE

```js
$('li').find('a').on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.main-content').load(href + 'content-ajax');
});
```

```css
.ajax-img {
    margin-top: 8em;
    float: left;
}

.ajax-img2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-top: -5em;
}

.ajax-nadpis {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 800px;
    font-size: 2.7em;
}

.ajax-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -13em;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 18em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    
}

ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

//FIRST HTML PAGE

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vlastna responzivna stranka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tinos&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
    <h2 class="podnadpis">Automaticke nacitanie clanku pomocou ajaxu (bez refreshu stranky)</h2>
    <section class="ajax">
        <div class="section-container">
            <div class="img-holder">
                <img src="ajax-IMGs/talltales.png" class="tall-tales-logo" alt="logo tall tales">
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
    
    <article id="article">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="ajax1.html">Shroudbreaker</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript.html">Skeleton Lords</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-ajax">
            <img src="ajax-imgs/graymarrow.png" class="ajax-img" alt="">
                <h3 class="ajax-nadpis">SKELETON LORDS</h3>
                <p class="ajax-text">Tall Tales – Shores of Gold introduces Skeleton Lords, imposing characters clambering out of the oldest legends into the present day. Meaner than any of the bony marauders you’ve fought so far, these intimidating adversaries can only be encountered by following the story as it unfolds. Be prepared for anything when seeking out Skeleton Lords – these resourceful foes will resist any attempt to send them back to their resting place beneath the sands. They’re big, tough and full of surprises…</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SECOND HTML FILE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vlastna responzivna stranka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles2.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tinos&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <article id="article">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="ajax1.html">Shroudbreaker</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript.html">Skeleton Lords</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-ajax">
        <img src="ajax-imgs/shroudbreaker.png" class="ajax-img2" width=700px height=600px  alt="">
            <h3 class="ajax-nadpis">SHROUDBREAKER</h3>
            <p class="ajax-text">The Shroudbreaker is the first Tall Tale in the Shores of Gold Arc. The Tale Book can be voted for on the table next to the Mysterious Stranger in the Tavern of any Outpost. The Tall Tale can be voted to be cancelled at the Ship's Voyage Table. Players can unlock three Checkpoints during this Tall Tale. If they wish to continue the Tall Tale at a later time, they can vote on any acquired Checkpoints at the Voyage Table.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the errors I am getting
[image]

Comment: You just need : .load(href)

Comment: that surely helped thanks, however, the are two rows of links now,  in short, there are the same links just duplicate. any idea on how to remove them?

Comment: `.load(href + ' .content-ajax');` **Spaces is important**

Comment: Maybe look in : main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Load page content using AJAX

First of, you should use a templating engine (i.e: PHP) since it makes it infinitely easier to just change a head tag in one place than in *N* files. Same goes for scripts in *footer* etc.

Every page should be accessible on its own (via URL) but give the feel of no tab refresh, here's where AJAX comes at play:

`header.php` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title><?= $page_title ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#!" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

and `footer.php` :

```html
    <footer>
        &copy; <?= date("Y") ?> - Lorem Ipsum
    <footer>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Create three files `index.php`, `about.php` and `contact.php` like the following and change the `<h1>` text respectively

```html
<?php
$page_title = "Home";
include 'header.php';
?>

<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>This is Home page</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

```html
<?php
$page_title = "About";
include 'header.php';
?>

<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>This is About page</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

```html
<?php
$page_title = "Contact";
include 'header.php';
?>

<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>This is Contact page</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Finally here's the JS `script.js` file:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Read history states
    window.onpopstate = function (e) {
        if (e.state) {
            $("#content").html(e.state.html);
            document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
        }
    };

    $("#nav").on("click", "a", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior

        const URL = $(this).attr("href"); // get page URL
        const name = $(this).text(); // get page name
        document.title = name;

        // AJAX LOAD and pushState for browser history
        $("#page").load(URL + " #content", function (data) {
            const html = $(data).find("#content").html();
            const pageTitle = $(data).find("h1").text();
            // Handle history and  browser's AddressBar
            window.history.pushState({html, pageTitle}, "", URL);
        });
    });
});
```

Install PHP and set the `php` binaries paths in your Environment Variables (Windows).
Open terminal from your project folder and spin up a lightweight PHP cli-server:

```sh
php -S localhost:8080
```

and head to http://localhost:8080

The above is crawler friendly, meaning that a crawler visiting your page can index every other page and its contents.