# How to change only one part of a webpage/ keep the same template throughout the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

Ive made a homepage/ template for a website. However, to add more pages i would have to copy this template with the added content of each page. Obviously, this would mean changing every single page if i make a small change to the template.

How do i have a main index page and then for every other page just change the content?

[image: Visual explanation of what i am trying to achieve]

Comment: Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67285002/383904) ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention a library of any kind in your question, so I will recommend a JavaScript library to you: React.JS.

With React.JS, you could utilize the routing system and make your template be returned for every route. However, you could change the props on each route in order to change the content that you want to be changed. Here's an example, in unfunctional code, of what you can do in React.JS:

```
<Route path='/hi'>
    <Template content={'Hello!'} />
</Route>
<Route path='/bye'>
    <Template content={'Goodbye!'} />
</Route>
<Route path='/'>
    <Template />
</Route>
```

To learn more about React, here's the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

I really recommend that you use React for this situation, I think it would make the development a lot easier. If you are already using a library, give me a comment and I will try to help you out for that specific library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My current site is just made with Bootstrap/html/css.

Comment: Okay! Is your plan currently to have multiple HTML files and have different server-side routes for all of them via Apache or NGINX?

Comment: I have no idea, web development isn't really my speciality. I think i might use Flask or Golang unless theres a quicker way. All i need is a template with consistent header and footer, and to be able to change the content easily when i add a new page.

Comment: This will have to be done with either a JavaScript library or a backend library, like you mentioned either Flask or a Go library. I would personally recommend Express.JS for backend since it is really easy and only takes a few lines of code. Anyways, just make the backend library change the content of the HTML file for different routes.

Comment: Okay! I don't know if stackoverflow has any private messages or anything like that, but if you need any help in the future, just find a way to contact me and I can help you out as much as needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `JavaScript`. Just select the tags that needs to be improved and change their content by doing something like this

```
document.queryselector('.classname' or '#idname').innerHTML="your new content";
```

If you want to change an image, then try doing

```
document.queryselector('.classname' or '#idname').src="url of your image";
```